# Java inheritance and extends Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, constructor

I am studying Java and Thread and have a question about inheritance.

For example I have a parent class called `SuperThread` and this thread has `LocalThread` and `NetThread`.

I would like to use `SuperThread`'s constructor in `LocalThread` and `NetThread`.

for example:

```
public class SuperThread{
    Private String name;
    Private int size;

    SuperThread(String name, int size){
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }    
}

public class LocalThread extends Thread{
    String path = "";
    LocalThread(String name, int size, String path){
    Super(name, size);
    this.path = path;
}

public class NetThread extents Thread{    
    //Share common constructor from parent class, but it was own part
    }
}
```

However, I know that I have to extend `Thread` in order to use thread.

Is there any way to extend Threads while inheriting constructor from parent's class ?

Comment: You shouldn't be extending `Thread` for this exact reason (and others); there's no multiple inheritance in Java.

Comment: You only need inheritance when you need to refer to instances of the subclass as if they were instances of the supertype. In other words, unless you have some method that accepts parameters of type `SuperThread`, and you are planning to pass `LocalThread` and `NetThread` instances to that method, you don't need inheritance.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Runnable` interface and override `run` method in your `LocalThread` class.

```
public class LocalThread extends SuperThread implements Runnable{
   String path = "";
   LocalThread(String name , int size, String path){
      super( name, size);
      this.path = path;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      //some actual job here
   }
}
```